# Get level of factors from trained randomForest in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I have a trained randomForest model in R, that I load from an RDS file. One of the predictors is a non-ordered factor, I no longer have the training data that was used to produce this, but would like to know what levels this factor had so I can ensure data I am trying to predict on only has those levels for this factor. Is this possible?

Comment: Please check variable names (among categoricals) because while creating one-hot-encoding/`model.matrix` level value gets appended to variable names. From there some string manipulation and you can get levels :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data structure of a `randomForest` object varies slightly depending on whether it was trained using a "formula interface" or "matrix interface". However, the information about independent variables is stored in both cases as a list object `randomForest$forest$xlevels`.

```
library("randomForest")

df = read.csv("Audit.csv")

rf = randomForest(Adjusted ~ ., data = df)
print(rf$forest$xlevels)
print(rf$forest$xlevels["Education"])
```

Comment: This is perfect, I tried everywhere but the forest object, thank you!